てもいいもんだよね at the end of this sentence?

The character laying down is a horror writer who likes to visit spooky places. He asks his editor "which place would you like to visit?" and he's against it.

人の念が籠もる場所は何度行ってもいいもんだよ

My reading of the sentence is akin "visiting places filled with people's feelings/thoughts is nice" but I can't quite wrap my ahead around the usage at the end. I don't assume it's a classical てもいい at least.


人の念が籠もる場所
a place filled with people's strong emotions
は (topic marker)
何度行っても
no matter how many times one goes
いい
is nice; is good
もんだ (indicates something is a general/cold fact)

Why should I use わけだ and not ものだ in this sentence?
How to parse 親も辞書を買ってやったかいがあるってもんだ


よね (sentence-final particles)

So a literal translation is:

人の念が籠もる場所は何度行ってもいいもんだよね。
A place filled with people's strong emotions is always good, no matter how many times you visit it, you know.

